# How to check if the problem is of clean url when migrating the database from one server to another?

Tags: 7, database, migrations, uri

After uploading the my local db on server my site was not working and what I was getting was white screen of death. After few hours of struggling I found that as the server was not configured for clean url and the in the database the clean url settings was ON that was causing the problem.

Is there any way we can come to know if the problem is of the clean url in such scenario.

Also I can't use the backup and migrate module as the database size was too large.

Comment: Well yes, you should always make sure your server supports the software you're trying to run on it _before_ uploading it. To check for mod_rewrite in Apache, run `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` and scan the list for `rewrite_module`

Comment: @Clive Thanks for the method suggested by you for checking the mod_rewrite module status, actually the problem was that the site was present in the multi domain environment and the site was present in a sub folder so the "RewriteBase /" line in htaccess was causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is advised to [**turn off** the **CLEAN URLs**](https://drupal.org/node/776864) before migrating the database from one server to server.

Reason behind you were not able to see errors on white screen of death may be error reporting being turned off, if that is the case than you may try adding the following lines in setting.php to turn on error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

> Also check the entry's of "watchdog" table if you are getting white screen of death upon migration.

Comment: **Watchdog** table keeps the record of all site errors, so it helps a lot especially in finding the database error, you will surely get the clue for **CLEAN URL** issue from there.